# Aggregate my quantity sum in a way that doesn't lead to the storeID repeating?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2019

I am writing a SQL query that needs to show the total number of orders from each store. The issue I am running into, is that while I can figure out how to sum the orders by product and each product is only sold by one store, I can't figure out how to total the orders by store alone

This is the code I currently have

```
SELECT storeID AS [STORE], Product_ID
    , SUM(quantity) AS [ORDERS BY STORE]
FROM Fulfillment, Store
GROUP BY storeID, Product_ID;
```

This line of code leads to a repeat of storeID in the results, where ideally, I would only want storeID to be included in the results once with the total quantity of all of Product_ID being included. I tried to remove Product_ID from the GROUP BY statement, but this resulted in the following error

> Column 'Fulfillment.Product_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm new to SQL and am trying to learn, so any help and advice is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just remove product_id from the `select` part as well. If all you're concerned about is the store_id, no need to include product_id in there at all.

Comment: You need to carry out a proper explicit join, not that old style comma join for which you haven't added a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

@ZLK is correct that if your goal is a total number of units ordered ("quantity") of any product, simply remove the [product_id] column from the SELECT and GROUP BY.

However, it appears that you're referencing two tables ("FROM Fulfillment, Store") and not specifying how those tables are joined, creating a cartesian join - all rows in one table will be joined to all rows in the other table. If the [storeID] and [quantity] fields are available in the Fulfillment table, I recommend removing the Store table reference from the FROM clause (so "FROM Fulfillment" alone).

One last note: You mention that you want to count "orders". In some circumstances, an order may have multiple products and a quantity > 1. If your goal is the total number of "orders" regardless of the number of products or quantity of products on an order, you'll want to use "COUNT(DISTINCT orderID) as [Orders]" (where "orderID" is the reference to the unique order number).